# how to crop image in to pieces using - (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight

Tags: iphone

i need to crop single image into 9 pieces.

for that most of them suggest the fallowing method.

```
 - (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight
```

But i did n't fine any where how do it using this.

can any one please help me.

how can i crop image using this method.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: Dude ... you already asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743242/how-to-crop-image-in-to-pieces-programmatically/4744599#4744599 (by the way, the answer I gave in your previous question is correct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight is not cropping the image. It allows you to stretch an image with vertical and horyzontal margin.

In the doc you will read :

> stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:
>   Creates and returns a new image object
>   with the specified cap values.

To crop an image you should use CGImageCreateWithImageInRect :

> CGImageCreateWithImageInRect
>   Creates a bitmap image using the data contained within a subregion of an existing bitmap image.

You can achieve what you want with a method such as this one :

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromImage:(UIImage *)image inRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGImageRef sourceImageRef = [image CGImage];  
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(sourceImageRef, rect);  
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef scale:1.0 orientation:image.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
    return newImage;
}
```

Hope this helps,
Vincent