# How to crop an image into polygon shape in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to crop an image which is on the UIImageview into any shape

Comment: This may help u..
[ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305056/cropping-image-in-iphone/12197457#12197457 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CGImageMask`.

A sample exists in the class QuartzMaskingView of Apple's QuartzDemo.

Answer (score 2):

You set the clipping path and voila:

```
// Load image thumbnail
    NSString *imageName = [self.picArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];        
    CGSize imageSize = image.size;
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);    

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.0);
    // Create the clipping path and add it
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:imageRect cornerRadius:5.0f];
    [path addClip];
    [image drawInRect:imageRect];
    UIImage *roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This code loads an image and creates a path by rounding the rectangle, the result is that the final image has been clipped, i.e. rounded corners. RoundedImage is the result.