# Animation Like frames/Blocks

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation

Does anyone know how to animation an image in Objective-C like it is done at
[Famous Brands](http://www.famousbrands.co.za/) (Requires Flash Player to see)

Comment: You Mean animation shown on intro?

Comment: Yes Blocks type...with uiimageView

Comment: If your example requires plug-ins, _please_ describe how it looks so that more people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Take your image and slice it in parts with your favorite photo app. Create an `imageView` for each image and add it to a new `UIView` which play the role of the image container. Now add this `UIView` to your main view.

If you want to animate it simply iterate through all `imageViews` inside your container view and start the following animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                        delay: i * 0.3
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         currentImageView.alpha = 0.0;
                         currentImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0, 1.0);
                     }
                     completion:nil
];
```

Where currentImageView is the current `imageView` in the loop and i the iterator var.

It would be even better to slice the original Image with `CoreGraphics`, so you don't have to do it manually as stated above but that's a little bit more work.

Comment: How can we do this with Coregraphics?

Comment: You mean to cut one large image in smaller parts?
In that case take a look at this: [how to crop an image into pieces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743242/how-to-crop-image-in-to-pieces-programmatically)